# Installing Opengeo Suite on Ubuntu 13.04 - " trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/shp2pgsql-gui' "?

Tags: installation, ubuntu, boundless-suite, linux

I am trying to upgrade Opengeo Suite from 2.0 to 4.0, specifically for the upgrade of PostGis 2.0 to 2.1, I followed the instructions outlined on this page: http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/installation/ubuntu/upgrade.html
But had no success.

I realized I hadn't fully installed opengeo-client or postgis 2.1, so I used apt-get install and received this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
opengeo-client : Depends: postgis-2.1 (>= 2.1.0) but it is not installed
postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 : Depends: postgis-2.1 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

So I used -f and received..

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  postgis-2.1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  postgis-2.1
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
28 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/701 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,839 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'postgresql-9.2-postgis2' missing; assuming                     package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 384786 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking postgis-2.1 (from .../postgis-2.1_2.1.0-1+opengeo_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/postgis-2.1_2.1.0-1+opengeo_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/shp2pgsql-gui', which is also in package postgis 1.5.3-2ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/postgis-2.1_2.1.0-1+opengeo_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I was recommended to go back and forth with **apt-get upgrade** and **apt-get -f install** to isolate the issue. But I am assuming that Postgis 1.5 is still in use, but I cannot find where to remove it. (If it is possible to do a complete wipe of the Opengeo suite then I can also do that if it would be simpler, all of my data is backed up)

I am not experienced in Linux. Most of my work is on the GIS/Web side.

My Ubuntu release is: Ubuntu 13.04 Raring

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue on 12.04 while upgrading from 3.0 to 4.0.2.

The following command seems to solve it in my case:

```
sudo dpkg --purge opengeo-postgis-shapeloader
```

And then run the opengeo upgrade command again.